# What is wrong with this proof that for an open subset of a metric space relatively open=open?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

To prove $A$ is open in $E$ $\implies$ $A$ is open in $X$, where $A\subseteq E\subseteq X$ and $E$ is open in $X$, I start out with $E \subseteq X $ being open implies that for any $e \in E$, $\exists \epsilon$ such that $B_x(e,\epsilon)\subseteq E$ (where the ball with the subscript of $x$ implies it is a ball in $X$, as opposed to E). Now we take a relatively open subset $A \subseteq E$, we can apply the above statement with $a \in A$ rather than $e \in E$. Now we look at the set $S= \left\{ d(a,y) | y \in B_x(a,\epsilon)-A  \right\} $. We can take $\gamma = \inf S$ since $S$ is a subset of the real numbers. Now considering $B_x(a,\gamma)$, we can see that $B_x(a,\gamma)-A$ is empty, otherwise we would arrive at a contradiction involving $\gamma$ being the greatest lower bound of $S$. Therefore, $B_x(a,\gamma)\subseteq A$, so for every $a \in A$, there is a neighborhood in $X$ about a contained in $A$, so $A$ is open in $X$..

Obviously, this cannot be complete as I never actually used the fact that $A$ is relatively open in $E$. The only qualm I have with this is I never showed there is guarantee that $\gamma$ is non-zero, which looks simple to do using the fact that $A$ is relatively open in $E$. As I write this, I think this could be what I was missing at first as if $A$ were relatively closed, we could have $\gamma =0$ if our $a$ lie on the boundary of $A$, so the condition that $A$ is relatively open in $E$ is necessary. However, this is the first time I have ever looked at any sort of topology so I figured I would ask. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your construction could leat to an empty set of distances. What happens when $A=B_x(a,\epsilon)$? E.g., let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, $E=(-1,1)$, and $A=(0,1)$. Then take $a=\frac{1}{2}$, and $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, so $B_X(a,e) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid |x-\frac{1}{2}|\lt \frac{1}{2}\} = (0,1)$. Then $S=\{d(a,y)\mid y\in (0,1)-(0,1)\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah. If This is the case though wouldn’t the ball already be a subset of A? So if I changed the above to specify the case where S is and isn’t empty, would this work? Is this on the right track at least? Thanks for any help

Comment: You would need to check all the possibilities. What happens if $S$ is empty? What happens if the infimum is $0$? And you never really relate your ball to $A$. What happens if the ball  you picked, which only witnesses the fact that $E$ is open, happens to completely swallow $A$? Too many cases to consider. Your approach is fraught with issues, not just one. I don't think this is a good approach, *precisely* because you are never using your assumptions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin could you give me some intuition on where to start? I felt like what I was outlining made sense intuitively but I guess I’m making the wrong approach. I’d appreciate any help

Comment: Let $a\in A$; then there is an open set in $E$ that contains $a$ and is completely contained in $A$. That means that there is an open set $O$ in $X$ such that $a\in E\cap O\subseteq A$ (definition of "open in $E$"). But both $E$ and $O$ are open in $X$, so $E\cap O$ is open in $X$. So there exists $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $B_X(a,\epsilon)\subseteq E\cap O$...

Answer (score 1):

When you say $A$ is open in $E$, you mean that there exists an $\text{open ball}$(**in $E$**) around every $a$, which is completely contained in $E$, it’s crucial that the ball is open in $E$, this open ball can be open in $E$ but not in $X$.